# Disable parse server logger during unit test of cloud code

Tags: unit-testing, logging, parse-server

all. I'm trying to implement an app that using parse server as backend.
And I'm trying to use mocha/chai to do the unit test for the cloud code function.

Like the code below.

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { server } = require('../index.js');
const Parse = require('parse/node');

let loggedUser;
let loggedUserSessionToken;

describe('SMS APIs', function() {
  before('Initialize parse server.', function(done) {
    Parse.initialize("appId");
    Parse.serverURL = 'http://localhost:1337/parse';
    done();
  });

  after('Close server', function(done) {
    done();
    server.close();
  });

  it('Pass', function(done) {
    expect(1).to.equal(1);
    done();
  })
)};
```

After I run `yarn mocha`. The command line shows lots of log message. It is hard to read the mocha test result. like the picture below. Is there any method to turn off parse logger?
[command line logger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpGXs.png)

Comment: Have you succeeded to run tests with MOCKED Parse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look how the parse-server repo does it:  [helper.js](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/a185c97557eed2459df3d925731e1f2a8565abd5/spec/helper.js#L72)

the key is to set 'silent: true' in the parse-server configuration.

I do this by using the wonderful [config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config) package, creating a `test.js` config that sets `silent` to `true` and then setting `NODE_ENV=test` when running my unit tests.  Sounds like a lot to do, but this pattern is commonly reused for many things.  Good luck!

Comment: I have another question. While testing, I'll start a whole new parse-server and connected it to a clean mongodb. Which means there are not exist pre-defined classes and schema. How can I duplicate a copy of classes and schema from staging server, and apply it to the testing server when it started? thank you.

Comment: well, you could do that using the [schema api](http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#schema). but that's not what I do.  I have a test helper class that objects that match my code.  Not saying its better....  I would suggest taking a look at the parse-server unit tests which is what I modeled what I do after.....